# NOT IN/ NOT EXISTS || I am trying to get the IDs missing in a specific date. The table now tracks date and ID if manifested only

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, exists, not-exists, notin

I have a table with Date, ID and Volume such as in below:

| Date | ID | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23/11/22 | 999 | 10 |
| 23/11/22 | 888 | 10 |
| 23/11/22 | 777 | 10 |
| 22/11/22 | 888 | 10 |
| 22/11/22 | 777 | 10 |

I would like the ID to appear in the ID column in 22/11/22 even though it manifested 0 volume and to create a flag such as below telling Day over Day (DoD) which ones are "Not Active":

| Date | ID | Volume | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23/11/22 | 999 | 10 | Active |
| 23/11/22 | 888 | 10 | Active |
| 23/11/22 | 777 | 10 | Active |
| 22/11/22 | 999 | 0 | Inactive |
| 22/11/22 | 888 | 10 | Active |
| 22/11/22 | 777 | 10 | Active |

I attempted the following but return 0 rows and I do not know what to do next..

`    select distinct csmp.date
csmp.mcid as id
,count(*)  as volume

```
from volume csmp

where id NOT IN
       (select csmp.mcid
        from calc.swa_manifested_packages csmp               
        GROUP BY csmp.mc
        )

GROUP BY
csmp.mcid`
```

thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select 
    a.Date
    ,b.id
    ,coalesce(c.volume,0) volume
    ,coalesce(c.status,'Inactive') volume
from 
(Select distinct Date from volume) a
cross join (Select distinct id from volume) b
left join volume c
on a.date=b.date
and b.id=c.id
```

Basically we create all combinations of ID and DATE, and left join them on the volume table.

Comment: Hi, however I do not have the c.status column, I would need to create. Would I just use a case when there?